# Compare ISO 8601 periods in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iso8601

I am trying to compare ISO 8601 periods in JavaScript to see which period has a greater duration than the other. For example: P6M (6 months) is greater than PT10M (10 minutes).

I can't find anything out of the box which helps, perhaps you guys can help me achieve this.

Comment: Be careful, it's pretty easy comparing durations in units of weeks or less, but problematic for months and years. You need to have agreement on how to convert month and year durations to values, e.g. the first 6 months of the year has 181 or 182 days, the second 6 months has 184 days. So is P0.5Y == P6M always? Is P0.5M == P2W ? Is P1M == P4W? or P30D?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing available *OOTB* using the native javascript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object but [**Moment.js**](http://momentjs.com) handles your *ISO8601* durations just fine *(and there's little point re-inventing the wheel here...)*

***e.g.*** the following [**demo**](http://jsbin.com/xayomasuta/1/edit?js,console) prints: `"6 months is greater than 10 minutes"`

```
var d1 = moment.duration('P6M'),
    d2 = moment.duration('PT10M');

console.log(
    d1.humanize()
  + ( d1 < d2 ? ' is less than ' : ' is greater than ' )
  + d2.humanize()
);
```

Comment: Perhaps, but given P1Y and P12M you'll get something like "1 year is equal to 1 year" but for P1M and P4W you'll get "1 month is not equal to 1 month". Should P4W be converted to "one month" or "4 weeks"? Periods are tricky. Converting an ISO 8601 period to a value in, say, seconds, is about 10 lines of code. But how many seconds in 1 year? 1 month?

Comment: If I understand correctly, ISO periods can't be compared without a specific points in time (ISO date), because the duration of a period depends on that date. P1M is 86400 seconds shorter starting at February 1st in 2015 than in 2016, because 2016 is a leap year and there is thus an additional day. It may also need to take DST, holes in calendar systems and leap seconds into account.